# Integral inversion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inverse, integral-transforms

Say I know this function
$$ F(u) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) m\left(\frac{u}{x}\right) \mathrm d x$$
where $m(x)$ is a Fourier transform of an infinitely differentiable real function, whose maximal value is $1$, minimal value is $0$, and for every argument less than $0$ or greater than $1$ it is $0$. ($m(x)$ is known)

How can I get $f(x)$ knowing $F(u)$?

Comment: it is a multiplicative convolution : $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) m(e^u/x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(e^y) m(e^{u-y})e^y dy = [f(e^y)e^y \ast m(e^y)] (u)$ (this time a normal additive convolution) so the conditions for recovering $f$ from that are well known